# Auto add new model_field on request in Django || DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a simple REST-API project.

Here is my models:

```
class Human(Model):
    height = IntegerField()
```

And I have a serializer for that:

```
class HumanSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    height = IntegerField(required=True)
```

Very clear and simple!
But! What I want is to be able to add additional fields to my Human model, and automatically migrate those changes to the database, and add a new field to serializer that would be related to the new model field.

> For example, lets say that the client want to add a new field called
>   "weight". So a developer won't do anything, because the backend will
>   automatically receive that request, will automatically create a new
>   field to Human model, automatically create a new field to serializer,
>   and automatically create a migration.py file related to those changes.

Is there a way to achieve that ? What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Will it contain *relations* to other models? If so what should happen then?

Comment: No, it probably won't atleast for now, I just want this process to be completely automatical, is that even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the `Human` model has *no* relations (like a `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`, `OneToOneField`, etc.) to models, then you can simply specify this with `fields = '__all__'`:

```
class HumanSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = '__all__'
```

But relations to other models will still have to be included manually, since there can be several ways to handle this:

1. by ignoring them;
2. by adding the `id` (or URI) to the object;
3. by serializing the related objects as well;
4. ...

Perhaps serializing the related objects looks like a straightforward choice, but this can result in infinite recursion if for example an object (perhaps indirectly) points to itself, so that would mean that the serialization of that objects contains the serialization of that object. Even if it does not create recursive loops, it can still blow up the response gigantically, so even if this recursion is not possible, it might not be ideal to transfer thousands of objects in a single response. Finally a reason why this might not be advisable is that through those relations, we might end up into models that store *sensitive* information (for example if an object is linked to a model that is linked to one or more users, then your API would expose details of the users), which might not be a good idea.

If for example `Human` would have a reference to a (hypothetical) `Ssn` object, then you can serialize this as well with:

```
class HumanSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ssn = SsnSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Yeah I know that I can include all fields in serializers, Im curious about how to generate and migrate auto-generated migration files and how to add new fields directly in models.py and do all this automatically

Comment: By running `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`? But there are good reasons why this is not automatically, since this can only be done *semi*-automatically. If you for example rename a field, then there are several options, according to Django it can mean that (a) you renamed the field, (b) removed a field and created a new one. Furthermore another open question is what to do with the data, how to migrate old data, etc. Since migrations can typically result in (dangerous) data loss, it is better not to do this automatically.

Comment: Yeah but, I want those commands to be launched by the script itself and not by my hands

Comment: @Madi7: well you can run these in the deploy script, like (for example the `.yaml` of the Docker), but as said before, doing migrations automatically has a lot of dangerous (!) consequences. Since it can result in data loss. I would really advice against this. The pain of checking migrations is not much compared to the pain of losing data, or having a corrupt database.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it, but then, how some client_related_management systems work ? Because they allow users to add new fields to existing models via simple POST request, and from that point they can fill those new created fields with data

Comment: Typically that is done with an EAV: Entity-Attribute Value table I think: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model. So the model does not change, it creates an extra level of indirection.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time, hope EAV will help me achieve what I want